# Unable to find translations in WordPress theme

Tags: themes, translation

I am using Zerif Lite as theme for my WordPress website. It is developed for English users, but 98% of the theme settings and Customizer are translated (in french for me).

I have checked the `languages` directory looking for `.mo`, `.po` and `.pot` files but nothing related to the french translation.

I have done a research (search tool in DreamWeaver) into the whole Wordpress directory with a french string found into the theme settings, but nothing found either.

I cannot figure out how the theme is able to translate everything. Thanks for any help.

Comment: Have you asked the people at Zerif? Maybe they know how they pulled this trick.

Comment: @cjbj: That's what I am planning to do if no answer, but after having a look on their support about some other issues, I'd rather start asking here  ^_^

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are three usual possibilities:

1. Translation files somewhere in theme's directory.
2. Translation files in site's directory, defined by `WP_LANG_DIR` constant (typically `wp-content/languages`).
3. Theme's original strings are in different language, so that is its default state and it needs to be translated *to* English.

Comment: You were right, there is a `theme` directory in `wp-content/languages` where I can find `zerif-lite-fr_FR` .po and .mo files. Thanks a lot for your greatly appreciated help. Still another mistery... `Why DreamWeaver didn't found a string in that files that I can now manually find ?` Well, I am now able to translate missing parts, thanks again !